# How to set tooltip for user control (from style file)

Tags: wpf, controls, tooltip, styles

I created my control which looks like that

```
<UserControl BorderBrush="#A9C2DE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Class="WPFDiagramDesignerControl.Components.UcWBSBlock"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="86" Width="151" >

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Tooltip.xaml"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">

    <TextBox Name="txtBox"  Style="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}" >
    </TextBox>

</Grid>
```

I also have a file with style for tooltip "Tooltip.xaml"
How can I use this style for entire UserControl?
Usually I did this with that code

```
<TextBox ToolTip="{StaticResource tooltipname}"/>
```

But it was easy because file with style was in resource dictionary of control where I placed textbox. However I can't do sth like that

```
 <UserControl BorderBrush="#A9C2DE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="{StaticResource tooltipname"}/>
```

Because at this point my style isn't in resource dicionary yet.
I was trying to use this syntax

```
<UserControl.ToolTip>  </UserControl.ToolTip>
```

but I don't konow how should I refer to static resource

Maybe it is lame question but I just don't konow how to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just use DynamicResource instead of StaticResource to defer the lookup until runtime and then use the attribute syntax:

```
<UserControl ... ToolTip="{DynamicResource tooltipname}" ...
```

You can also write the StaticResourceExtension using element syntax so that you can write it after the Resources section:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Tooltip.xaml"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.ToolTip>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="tooltipname"/>
</UserControl.ToolTip>
```